# How to test and debug a Xamarin mobile app with a ASP.NET Web API 2 back-end and Facebook Login

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, facebook-login

this is crazy. I can't find a way for this.

I have a Macbook pro development machine: I use Xamarin Studio for developing a mobile app. Then, I launch a virtual machine running Windows, where I have Visual Studio and the back-end project, done with ASP.NET Web Api 2. The VM is bridged, and the communication between the Xamarin App and the back-end works perfectly.

Now I need to add the Facebook Login feature (through my back-end API). When I go to the Facebook app settings, I try to enter the local IP address of the bridged VM, but it gives error as it accepts only domain and subdomain names. It accepts "localhost" too, but it's not my case.

How can I setup this environment?? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you run Xamarin studio in the VM where you're running VS with the Web Api project, or at least an emulator? You won't be able to run an iPhone emulator, but could do Android.

Comment: I could, but 1) the app is iOS 2) after this initial phase on my laptop, I will have to assign the mobile dev to a developer, and the web api to another developer. How could they work together and test?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the mobile developer to be able to run an emulator on their machine which uses facebook to log into a web api site hosted on another developer's dev machine?

Comment: You have a Xamarin iOS development environment on one side, ASP.NET Web API 2 development environment on another side. How can you develop / test / debug Facebook login since FB allows localhost only?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup to what you want in a current project i'm working on, the only difference is that my api is running on a desktop instead of in a VM.

Is the web api running under localhost on the VM? If so, try changing the project start url for the api to the local ip of the VM.

So in the project settings instead of the startup url being "http://localhost:port/", change to something like "http://192.168.1.xxx:port". And then in the facebook app settings change website site url to the same as the new startup url.